# Lipschitz constant estimation of continuous selection of upper hemicontinuous multivalued function

Tags: lipschitz-functions, multivalued-functions, set-valued-analysis

I'm reading a book, [Set-Valued Analysis](https://books.google.co.kr/books?hl=ko&lr=&id=cVUl3smcGlcC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=set-valued+analysis&ots=GKxphbccSv&sig=VEeK9Dtg5D6XjgvFwkdf-ofMRhM#v=onepage&q=set-valued%20analysis&f=false), written by Aubin.

I'd like to estimate the Lipschitz constant of the continuous selection of upper hemicontinuous multivalued function by Theorem 9.2.1 of the book.
It says that if $F:X \rightarrow Y$ is an upper hemicontinuous multivalued function from a compact metric space $X$ to a Banach space $Y$ and the valued of $F$ are nonempty and convex, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a locally Lipschitz single valued map $f_{\epsilon}: X \rightarrow Y$ such that $\text{Graph}(f_{\epsilon}) \subset B(\text{Graph}(F), \epsilon)$.

Now I consider the case when $Y$ is also compact, which implies $f_{\epsilon}$ is Lipschitz continuous on $X$.
I wonder if we can estimate the Lipschitz constant of such selection ($f_{\epsilon}$) w.r.t. $\epsilon$.

In the proof of the theorem in the paper, the authors construct the selection $f_{\epsilon}$ by introducing locally Lipschitz functions denoted by $a_i:X \rightarrow [0, 1]$. Unfortunately, the authors left a reference for the construction, theorem 1.1.2 in [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642695148), but I cannot found it in the cited book.

Can anybody help me 1) how to construct such $a_i$'s and 2) a way to estimate the Lipschitz constant of $f_{\epsilon}$ if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, my purpose is to show that given a sequence of u.h.c. multivalued functions $F_j:X \rightarrow Y$ we can choose an equi-Lipschitz sequence of functions $f_{\epsilon, j}$ such that $f_{\epsilon, j}$ is an $\epsilon$-selection of $F_j$.
Here is my idea if we can actually choose such $a_i$'s described in the proof of the theorem.

As in the proof of theorem 9.2.1. in [Set-Valued Analysis](https://books.google.co.kr/books?hl=ko&lr=&id=cVUl3smcGlcC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=set-valued+analysis&ots=GKxphbccSv&sig=VEeK9Dtg5D6XjgvFwkdf-ofMRhM#v=onepage&q=set-valued%20analysis&f=false) (if it's correct), we can choose the finite open cover $ \{ \text{int}(B(x_i, \delta_{x_i}/4) \}_{i \in I}$ of $X$ and $a_i$'s described in the proof, independent of $j$.
The selection is given as $f_{\epsilon, j} = \sum_{i \in I} a_i(x) y_i$ with an associated point $y_j \in F_j(B(x_i, \delta_i/4))$.
Each $a_i$ is locally Lipschitz in a compact space $X$, then $a_i$ is Lipschitz continuous on $X$ (namely, with Lipschitz constant $L_i$; I don't understand why the authors did not conclude the theorem with Lipschitzness of $f_{\epsilon}$ because local Lipschitzness on a compact space $X$ implies Lipschitzness on the same space. Probably it's due to the generalised version of the theorem as commented above the theorem in the book). Then, for any $x, x' \in X$, $|f_{\epsilon, j}(x) - f_{\epsilon, j}(x)| \leq \max_{x \in X}\lVert x \rVert \cdot \sum_{i \in I}|a_i(x) - a_i(x')| \leq \tilde{L} \lVert x - x'\rVert$ where $\tilde{L} = \max_{x \in X} \lVert x \rVert \sum_{i \in I} L_i$. This implies that $\{ f_{\epsilon, j} \}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is equi-Lipschitz.

My curiosity is quite resolved but I would be appreciated if someone let me know 1) we can actually choose such $a_i$'s and 2) explicit estimation of the Lipschitz constant of $f_{\epsilon}$.